# Mensaje registro repetido en php y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Tengo un archivo en el cual se pueden subir varios archivos a la vez y grabarlo en la bd, pero no se como ponerle para que si el registro ya existe me mande un mensaje diciendo que el nombre del archivo ya existe que lo modifique si no que lo grabe

Tengo estos dos archivos con los que hago el proceso

Upload.php

```
<div class="file_upload">
    <form action="file_upload.php" class="dropzone">
        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <strong>Arrastra archivos a cualquier lugar para subirlos.</strong><br /><br />
            <span class="note needsclick">
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>        
</div>
```

File_upload.php

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){     
$upload_dir = "uploads/";
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$uploaded_file = $upload_dir.$fileName;    
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$uploaded_file)){
    //insert file information into db table
    $mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO uploads (file_name, us, upload_time)VALUES('".$fileName."','".$us."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_insert) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
```

estaba tratando con una condición que si file_name = $filename mande el mensaje si no que lo guarde

donde quiero que busque si ya existe el articulo es en la base de datos

Pero no se donde y como ponerlo correctamente
espero puedan ayudarme
saludos

Comment: Algo como `if (!is_file($uploaded_file)) { ACA TU CODIGO } else { ERROR! }`?

Comment: No queda claro dónde tiene que hacerse la verificación, si en la base de datos (buscando el nombre del archivo) o en las carpetas (verificando si el archivo existe). Por favor aclara ese punto pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Para lo que necesitas debes usar AJAX, por medio del cual puedes interactuar entre el servidor y el cliente; desde el cliente enviaras una petición ajax al servidor consultando por el registro y si está, que envíe el mensaje al usuario para que él cambie el nombre del archivo, no hay otro modo.

Comment: hola muchas gracias por su ayuda es en la base de datos donde quiero que busque

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar antes de realizar la insercion si el archivo fisico esta presente usando `file_exists(archivo)`

```
$uploaded_file = $upload_dir.$fileName;    
if (file_exists($uploaded_file)){
     // informar del error, retornar un mensaje/json/etc.
     die("Archivo ya existe");
}
if(move_uploaded_file(...)){ 
   // resto del codigo de insercion
```

Suponiendo que hay archivos que no estan fisicamente, pero si en la base de datos, debes chequear el registro en la base de datos:

```
$uploaded_file = $upload_dir.$fileName;    
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT 1 as result FROM uploads WHERE file_name='$uploaded_file'");
if ($result->num_rows>0){
     // informar del error, retornar un mensaje/json/etc.
     die("Archivo ya existe en base de datos");
}
if(move_uploaded_file(...)){ 
   // resto del codigo de insercion
```

Para asegurarte mejor, puedes incluso verificar ambas condiciones (archivo fisico y base de datos)

Comment: Hola muchas gracias  me sirvio el de archivo fisico pero no eh podido mostrar mi mensaje de duplicado en mi pagina de upload.php este es el codigo que utilizo

Comment: `if (file_exists($uploaded_file)){

     echo "<script>
                alert('Mensaje');
                window.location= 'upload.php'
      </script>";
 die("Archivo ya existe");
   

  }`